# protected and private declaration in .net

Tags: .net, oop, access-modifiers

Are there any difference/advantages between protected and private declaration apart from it not being accessible outside the class.

Comment: thats not a difference its a similarity

Comment: what i meant was if there were other uses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [accessibility modifiers](http://www.dotnetbips.com/articles/255f31ac-a304-4063-ad2d-93a790417f3c.aspx) - that's their point.

Comment: `Friend` and `internal` are synonymous

Answer (score 4):

`private` members are only accessible from within the class, `protected` members are also accessible by classes that inherit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this example from the MSDN:

```
class A 
{
   protected int x = 123;
}

class B : A 
{
   void F() 
   {
      A a = new A();  
      B b = new B();  
      a.x = 10;   // Error
      b.x = 10;   // OK
   }
}
```

See the a.x throws an error because you are trying to access the property from outside the class (calling the prop within A from inside the class B).  But b.x is ok, because you are calling it from inside B.  Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Members that have the `protected` *access modifier* are accessible in the derived classes. While those who have the `private` *access modifier* are accessible only within the same class.

Read about [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`struct` members can only be declared as `public`, `private` or `internal`.

`class` members can be declared as `public`, `protected internal`, `protected`, `internal`, or `private`.

[Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) on MSDN